# JavaScript lambda functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking to have a good example for using lambda functions or anonymous functions within JavaScript with no luck.

Does jQuery have built-in functions to implement lambda too?

Comment: Perhaps this article will help: [Javascript Jems - Lambda expressions](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1031-javascript-jems-lambda-expressions.html)

Answer (score 23):

In *JavaScript* these are called [*function expressions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#The_function_expression_.28function_operator.29) (using `function` as an operator as opposed to [*declarations*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#The_function_declaration_.28function_statement.29), using `function` as a *statement*), and can be named or anonymous.

It's really as simple as doing something that tells the compiler it is an expression (e.g. `var x =`) then writing a function normally, and adding a delimiter `;` on the end.

```
function invoke(lam) {
    console.log(
        lam()
    );
}

var lambda = function () {return 'foo';};

invoke(lambda); // "foo" logged
```

As with any *function* in *JavaScript*,  the scope is inherited from where it is defined, not where it is invoked.

Self-invoking and anonymous functions are nearly always *function expressions*. For self-invoking functions, the `(` before `function` means the code is interpreted as an *expression*, then the (preferred) `());` or (alternate) `)();` invokes it immediately.

You may need to remember that a *function expression* by itself **is not hoisted**. If you need hoisting for it to avoid a *Reference Error*, combine with `var`. The function itself will still not be fully available until the code passes the line where it is defined.

For a named *function expression* the name is only available **inside** the function and not outside (some old versions of IE leaked the name though). To describe this, I'll use two examples, one self invoking and one `var`d;

```
// self-invoked
(function foo() {
    console.log('inside:', foo); // foo is defined here
}());
console.log('outside:', foo); // ReferenceError: foo is not defined

// var
var bar = function foobar() {
    console.log('inside:', foobar); // foobar is defined here
    console.log('inside:', bar); // bar is defined here too (=== foobar)
};
bar(); // invoke
console.log('outside:', bar); // bar is also defined here, but..
console.log('outside:', foobar); // ReferenceError: foobar is not defined
```

Answer (score 16):

A lambda function (anonymous function) is really just a function declaration without a name (it can be assigned to a variable later and still technically be a lambda). One common example is a self-executing function:

```
(function(){
  /*
    do stuff
  */
})();
```

Another common example is passing a function as a parameter for an AJAX or JSONP callback, a timeout, or a `sort()`:

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        console.log('lambda!');
    },
    100
);
```

On the "receiving" end of a lambda, you invoke the function parameter as you would any other function:

```
functionThatUsesLamba(function(s) { console.log(s); });

function functionThatUsesLambda(logFn) {
  if (typeof(logFn) == 'function') {
    logFn('lambda');
  } else {
    throw "logFn must be a function!!!";
  }
}
```